# wp 3.3.1 ajax pagination issue, pages won't advance at all

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to add ajax pagination to wp 3.3.1 and can't get it to work. I got the ajax portion working, however the pages just won't advance. Basically everytime I click "next" it will reload the current page.

I have the following code, maybe some expert could give me some hint or help. I have demo site setup if you need to take a look it.

Here is the code

```
<div id="clip_block"><div id='contentInner'>
<?php echo $post->ID ?>
<?php

$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$wp_query->query('cat='.$post_categories.'&posts_per_page=6&paged='.$paged);
?>
<?php while ($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post(); ?>

/* my content */
                </div></div>

<?php endwhile; ?></div></div>
<div id='postPagination'>
<?php previous_posts_link('Newer Entries &raquo;') ?>
<?php next_posts_link('&laquo; Older Entries') ?>

</div>
```

This is what I have in my header:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

jQuery('#postPagination a').live('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var link = jQuery(this).attr('href');
    jQuery('#clip_block').html('Loading...');
    jQuery('#clip_block').load(link+' #contentInner');
});
});
```

jquery.js is loaded as well.

thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

I don't know for sure, but speaking from experience this isn't the best way to use AJAX in WordPress.  Whenever I use AJAX in WP, I specifically send the request to wp-includes/admin-ajax.php which handles the request.

Can you provide a link?  I'll take a look.

Comment: here is the demo site [link](http://www.alieoli.com/video/18341/)  under the main video, I would like to list all the videos that under the same category.  Paged with ajax    thanks